# Removing escaped quotes in SQLite3

Tags: ios5, sqlite, replace, escaping

All,

I am trying to clean up data in a SQLite database, that contains tons of escaped single and double quotes.

Example: \"Text\" has \'junk\' like this all over the place.

When I do a SELECT to see if the REPLACE function has the correct pattern, the REPLACE is not working:

```
-- replace escaped single quotes
SELECT id,subject,body,replace(body,"\\'","'") as `clean-body` 
FROM article
WHERE id=1118
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to escape the backslash. Try this in place of your original call to `replace`:

```
replace(body,"\'","'")
```

Comment: Here is how you can find rows to replace escaped single and double quoted strings:                                                SELECT id,subject,body,replace(replace(body,"\'","'"),'\"','"') as `clean-body` 
FROM article
WHERE id=1302